# share via (Gallery )activity not getting closed after sharing the image

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have added my app option in share via option that comes when we share any image in gallery through share via option. I am able to see my app in share via option. But the problem is once the image is shared and after that the gallery is opened then the gallery still shows the app activity which means gallery activity is not finished even after sharing the image. How to overcome this problem ?

Here is the line of code I've added in activity tag in Manifest file :

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: In .class file write code to close activity as another activity is pushed onto activity stack

Comment: @Apurva where you mean buy .class file? And on create can i clear activity stack?